# Webdriver IO control tests from excel file

Tags: javascript, jasmine, webdriver-io

I need to control the test cases that are needed to run from an excel file. We are using jasmine framework.
Consider there are 10 cases I need to control which cases should run based on a value given in the excel file like 'yes' or 'no'

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. What did you try/investiate?

Comment: Hi , i have no prior knowledge on webdriverio and jasmine. I have done the same using webdriver. I couldn't find a sample code to implement it.